# How to Access all the element from <class 'list'>

Tags: python, arrays, list, class

```
print(type(hum))
print(hum)
```

Output:

```
<class 'list'>
[BodyPart:0-(0.48, 0.19) score=0.78 BodyPart:1-(0.52, 0.37) score=0.64 BodyPart:2-(0.42, 0.38) score=0.65 BodyPart:3-(0.39, 0.58) score=0.43 BodyPart:4-(0.40, 0.65) score=0.30 BodyPart:5-(0.62, 0.36) score=0.53 BodyPart:6-(0.76, 0.58) score=0.46 BodyPart:7-(0.73, 0.71) score=0.20 BodyPart:8-(0.46, 0.86) score=0.14 BodyPart:11-(0.57, 0.85) score=0.09 BodyPart:14-(0.45, 0.16) score=0.81 BodyPart:15-(0.50, 0.15) score=0.75 BodyPart:16-(0.43, 0.18) score=0.48 BodyPart:17-(0.55, 0.16) score=0.81]
```

How can I access all those values individually from list? I want to put relevant information in the multidimensional array or DataFrame.

So can you help me access values from this 'hum' of type `<class 'list'>`?

Comment: Read about [lists](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/)

Answer (score 0):

To access each element of a list in python you can loop into each one of them:

```
for i in hum:
    print(i)
```

This will print each element of your list one by one